# Following a docker tutorial but tutorial and real output is different

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and trying to understand what this domain is. I stumbled upon following [tutorial](http://containertutorials.com/). I am a backend developer and liked this tutorial since it talks about micro-services BUT the tutorial doesn't explain the commands. For example, I am currently stuck at [following section of tutorial](http://containertutorials.com/alpine/alpine-apache-server-static-site.html).

I ran following command

```
docker run  -p 80:80 --name my-apache2-alpine-1  my-apache2-alpine
```

Here is output of this command on my terminal

```
$ docker run -p 80:80 --name my-apache2-alpine-1 my-apache2-alpine
[s6-init] making user provided files available at /var/run/s6/etc...exited 0.
[s6-init] ensuring user provided files have correct perms...exited 0.
[fix-attrs.d] applying ownership & permissions fixes...
[fix-attrs.d] done.
[cont-init.d] executing container initialization scripts...
[cont-init.d] 30-resolver: executing... 
[cont-init.d] 30-resolver: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 40-resolver: executing... 
[cont-init.d] 40-resolver: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] done.
[services.d] starting services
[services.d] done.
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[cont-finish.d] executing container finish scripts...
[cont-finish.d] done.
[s6-finish] syncing disks.
[s6-finish] sending all processes the TERM signal.
[s6-finish] sending all processes the KILL signal and exiting.
```

This command didn't result in expected result as pointed out in tutorial i.e., `http://localhost:80/myindex.html` is "unable to connect" i.e., server is not running there.

Now here are my questions

1. What is i am missing here, why i didn't get expected result as pointed out in tutorial?
2. Can someone explain the command that i ran above?

---

**UPDATE**
Here are the content of `Dockerfile`

```
~/docker-practice/static-site$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM smebberson/alpine-apache
ADD ./public-html/myindex.html /var/www/localhost/htdocs
~/docker-practice/static-site$
```

Comment: Last question is off-topic, fyi. Requests to find guides/tutorials is one of the close vote reasons. :(

Comment: I have removed the last question.

Comment: Can you include the actual text of the Dockerfile in your question?  It looks like you're running some kind of init system which is a little bit unusual.

Comment: I have added the content of the dockerfile in my question.

Answer (score 1):

> What is i am missing here, why i didn't get expected result as pointed out in tutorial?

First, I think you're following a bad tutorial. I would start with the documentation and examples available at https://docs.docker.com first. However, we can diagnose the problem.

It looks like Apache is failing, because your container exits immediately after starting Apache. When Apache fails, it writes messages to whichever path is configured via the `ErrorLog` directive in your Apache configuration.  We're going to first need to find out where that file is, and then we're going to need to inspect after trying to start Apache.

Let's start by spawning a shell from your image, bypassing the default behavior:

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint sh my-apache2-alpine
```

This will get you a shell. Try starting Apache by hand:

```
/ # httpd -DFOREGROUND
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
/ #
```

Now, let's find out where Apache is writing the error log. We can do that with the `apachectl -S` command:

```
/ # apachectl -S
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/var/www"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/localhost/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/www/logs/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/apache2/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=1000
Group: name="apache" id=1000
/ #
```

From the above output, we see that the main error log is `/var/www/logs/error.log`. If we look at that file, we see:

```
/ # cat /var/www/logs/error.log
[Wed Nov 20 01:22:25.012196 2019] [core:error] [pid 41] (2)No such file or directory: AH00099: could not create /run/apache2/httpd.pid
[Wed Nov 20 01:22:25.012226 2019] [core:error] [pid 41] AH00100: httpd: could not log pid to file /run/apache2/httpd.pid
/ #
```

We now know why Apache won't start: it wants to write a PID file to `/run/apache2/httpd.pid`, but there is no `/run/apache2` directory. There are a couple of ways of fixing that:

1. You can create the necessary directory in your Dockerfile:

   ```
   FROM smebberson/alpine-apache
   RUN mkdir -p /run/apache2
   ADD ./public-html/myindex.html /var/www/localhost/htdocs
   ```
2. You can create the directory at runtime via the `--tmpfs` command line option:

   ```
   docker run  -p 80:80 --name my-apache2-alpine-1  --tmpfs /run/apache2 my-apache2-alpine
   ```

Using either solution, you should find that your Apache container is now able to start correctly.

> Can someone explain the command that i ran above?

You ran:

```
docker run  -p 80:80 --name my-apache2-alpine-1  my-apache2-alpine
```

This creates a new container (`docker run`) from the `my-apache2-alpine` image. It assign the name `my-apache2-alpine-1` to the container (`--name my-apache2-alpine-1`), so you can use that name to manage that container rather than the container id. Finally, it publishes container port 80 on host port 80 (`-p 80:80`), so that you can access the web server as if it were running directly on your host.

Comment: thanks. this is really really good explanation. thanks for the link to docker tutorial. the problem with that tutorial is that it includes kubernetes right from the beginning. as someone who doesn't even understand docker, adding kubernetes will just confuse me